# Recursive H Trees using Turtle

Tags: python, recursion, drawing, turtle-graphics

I am trying to create a program using recursion that will create a tree of H like this (this is order 1): 
[H tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5tW8.png)

A H-tree of order zero is simply an H centred at the centre point with all the three lines of the H of the same line lengt
The function will receive a turtle object, an integer indicating the tree order, a centre point, and the length of the line. If the order is greater than zero, then four H-trees of a lesser order (order -1) and smaller length line (line length / 2) will be drawn centred at each of the four endpoints of the H drawn in step 1.

So far I have this:

```
import turtle

def drawHTree(length, depth):
    if depth > 0:
        turtle.forward(length / 2)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length / 2)
        turtle.left(90)

        drawHTree(length / 2, depth - 1)

        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)

        drawHTree(length / 2, depth - 1)

        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length / 2)
        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length / 2)
        turtle.left(90)

        drawHTree(length / 2, depth - 1)

        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length)
        turtle.right(90)

        drawHTree(length / 2, depth - 1)

        turtle.right(90)
        turtle.forward(length / 2)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(length / 2)

window = turtle.Screen()
drawHTree(200,2)
```

Any help or recommendation would be great! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: You say you are familiar with the turtle module. Can you show us code that draws an H-tree of order zero? Can you do that so that for each of the 4 tips of the H at some place in your code the turtle is at that tip with the same direction it had at the start? Do you understand recursion? Think those through and you will be almost done. If you still get stuck, show us your progress, especially the code so far, and get back to us by editing your question appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Your (raw) code above is correct if you fix the indentation.  You seem to have the key principles: first get it to draw an **H**; make sure the function leaves the turtle exactly where it was when the function was called.  Below is my revision to your code to address some style issues, to get the depth/order number to correctly match the desired drawing and match the stated API:

> The function will receive a turtle object, an integer indicating the
>   tree order, a centre point, and the length of the line

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def drawHTree(turtle, order, center, length):

    if order < 0:
        return

    if center is not None:
        turtle.up()
        turtle.goto(center)
        turtle.down()

    turtle.forward(length / 2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length / 2)
    turtle.left(90)

    drawHTree(turtle, order - 1, None, length / 2)

    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)

    drawHTree(turtle, order - 1, None, length / 2)

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length / 2)
    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length / 2)
    turtle.right(90)

    drawHTree(turtle, order - 1, None, length / 2)

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.right(90)

    drawHTree(turtle, order - 1, None, length / 2)

    turtle.right(90)
    turtle.forward(length / 2)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(length / 2)  # always leave the turtle where you found it!

yertle = Turtle()

drawHTree(yertle, 2, (0, 0), 200)

screen = Screen()

screen.exitonclick()
```

**PRODUCES**

[image]

Comment: thanks so much for your reply!
I am wondering how i implement the different orders
How do I do this in different levels?

Comment: @zmoores1, I don't understand your question other than to say, "change the third argument to `drawHTree(yertle, 200, 3)` as needed."

Comment: @zmoores1, I've adjusted the code so that depth 0 is a simple **H** and depth 1 produces the image you linked.

Comment: @zmoores1, I've also made the `drawHTree(turtle, order, center, length)` function match the arguments described in your explanation which is different than your code `drawHTree(length, depth)`.